# Concatenating input streams in C++

Tags: c++, input, concatenation

I am hoping to find a C++ class, ideally in a standard library, which accepts multiple input streams and constructs a single input stream which comprises all the input from the first stream, then all the input from the second stream, and so on.

For reference, in case it helps, a stream like that is called a concatenated input stream in at least one other environment (namely Common Lisp). "Concatenated" seems like a useful general description.

I can imagine some workarounds, and I'll probably resort to something if I can't find a suitable class, but I just want to make sure I'm not overlooking a neat solution before I do that.

Comment: There is no such class in the standard library.  But I have seen 3rd party classes floating around that can handle this. But asking for specific recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: But streams can be real-time, how do you want to tackle that? (i.e. TCP stream, console\terminal stream, etc.)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie true, but such classes still need to have a concept of EOF and input errors. A user would simply read all data from one stream, regardless of its type, and then move on to the next stream, repeating as needed.  That doesn't mean this approach makes sense for certain types of streams, though.  Maybe the OP just wants to limit it to, say, file/string streams.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Good point. I'm working with multiple file input streams, I guess that makes the problem simpler.

Comment: That one must be easy to implement. Maybe you should peek at boost.iostreams library to learn about models it use if you plan to manipulate with input processing. While it doesn't have exact match, a SeekableDevice model  is likely the best candidate to emulate combination of inputs.

Comment: If they are concurrent streams, I've heard the term "muxing" (combining) and "demuxing" (separating) streams.  Such as transporting multiple streams of data from one machine over a single connection to another machine (such as a monitoring machine, logging machine, or virtual console).

Comment: @Eljay thanks for your interest. I'm interested in serial combination (all of the first stream, then all of the second, etc.) instead of concurrent. Hope this clarifies the issue.